# Is it possible to have meals at Reykjavík-Keflavík airport after 11 PM?

Tags: airports, food-and-drink, iceland, kef

I have a flight early in the morning, and I'm planning to reach the airport around 11 PM without having had dinner. Are there any food places at the airport that still serve meals at that time?

Comment: I found that food options are very limited at Keflavík.

Comment: I second that. Not only in regard to opening hours, but just in general there's not a whole lot of food options in Keflavík airport in my experience.

Answer (score 4):

At Keflavík, there are scheduled arrivals and departures as late as 2AM. The tax free shop is open 24h, but it is difficult to find the opening hours for the other shops, cafés and restaurants. At least Kaffitár, a coffee shop, is open until 1AM and serves snacks and light meals.

Comment: There was also a small grocery shop with sandwiches.