# Is a restaurant open at Keflavik Airport at 4:30 am?

Tags: food-and-drink, kef, wow-air

I am considering an itinerary (WW126-WW810) which would have me arriving at KEF at 4:30 am and departing at 6:15 am. My problem with WOW air is that I don't really want to pay €14 or more for airline food that probably ranks somewhere in the middle of the [vomit meter](https://farm9.staticflickr.com/8744/16958953182_06852be094_b.jpg).

So, I went to the airport website, and learned that there are [a very few restaurants and coffee shops](http://www.kefairport.is/wheninkef/en/restaurants/) there. But... the web site would not tell me their opening hours! For every single place, it only states: "Open in accordance with flight schedule" which doesn't seem very predictable. I found [another question about food at KEF](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/34284/3221) here on Travel, but it only discussed late evening, and did not cover this early morning timeframe at all.

My basic question is, if I take these flights, am I going to be able to eat halfway decent food in Keflavik?

Comment: Be very careful flying Wow Air. They're almost always late. I never book a Wow itinerary with less than 3-4 hours transit time. (My first leg was once delayed 5 hours; the only reason I made my connection was because the second leg was delayed too.)

Comment: According to [sleepinginairports](http://www.sleepinginairports.net/europe/reykjavik.htm): *Food & Drinks - Food concessions throughout the airport operate according to flight schedules. At the time of this update, there are no 24-hour dining options. Food options include: Joe & the Juice • Loksins Bar • House of Food • Nord • Segafredo.* but *A small 24-hour general store is available landside.* - reading about security lines your problem might rather be time between flights.

Comment: Why not buy food at the origin airport or just take some with you?

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas WOW Air from LGW to KEF, 13% was 16–30 minutes late, 9% was 31–60 minutes late, 7% 1–3 hours late. For Icelandair same route it was 15/9/2. [Source](http://www.caa.co.uk/uploadedFiles/CAA/Content/Standard_Content/Data_and_analysis/Datasets/Punctuality_stats/2016/201601_Punctuality_Statistics.pdf). February, WOW Air, 10/6/10, Icelandair 11/10/3. March, WOW Air 8/6/9, Icelandair 17/9/1. I'd say that any flight from LGW is usually late, WOW Air or not…

Comment: @gerrit Statistics are statistics, but I've flown Wow 7 times in the past 2 years (most recently June) and at least one leg on all 7 itineraries was delayed departing or landed late. So, from my personal perspective their on-time rate trends to 0. But that's just my personal experience.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas I usually avoid low cost carriers, for this and other reasons. But WOW promise that if I buy a single ticket with them and miss the connection that [they will be responsible](https://wowair.co.uk/customer-service/faq/airport-and-checking/i-need-catch-connecting-flight-how-long-do-i-need-wait-airport/), which most LCCs apparently do not. Of course, if the next flight isn't fairly soon after, then the whole thing is pointless and I should have spent a bit more for a ticket on a more traditional carrier.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas I've flown with Wow twice in the past two years and landed (nearly) on-time twice.  Either way, I would expect that if you buy a single transatlantic ticket with transfer at Keflavík that the airline takes care of the consequences in case of delays, which means the worst that can happen is a free 24 hour stopover in Iceland?

Comment: A hotdog from the street vendor costs more than $6 USD; I can't *afford* a free stopover in Iceland. ;-)

Comment: I have no opinion about the quality of the food served on WOW but I frequently buy snacks or drinks from other low-cost airlines. Psychologically, you feel shortchanged because other airlines did not or do not charge extra for the same thing but usually it's cheaper than at the airport…

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Update:** I originally wrote this answer long before WOW airline ceased operation. With it gone, morning traffic in KEF starts about 1 hour later. The basic point remains, though, that restaurants are open during the 'connection period' between European and North American flights.
However, during COVID this may not be accurate.

Yes, there will be restaurants open at that time.  I took one of WOW's 6am flights just a few weeks ago and all of the restaurants were open by the time I got through security at around 4:40.

This is actually a very busy time for KEF airport as a lot of North American flights arrive between 4 and 6 and a lot of European flights depart between 6 and 8.

Note, however, that these are airport restaurants and priced accordingly. Buying food during your flight may not be any more expensive (although with fewer options). The WOWAir in flight menu can be found here: http://vefbirting.oddi.is/wow/wow_me_summer_2016/files/assets/basic-html/page-61.html (I usually have the baguette, decent for airline food).

Restaurant options in the airport (airside): http://www.kefairport.is/wheninkef/en/restaurants/

Comment: Also worth noting is that the restaurants and duty free accepted euros and US dollars (bad exchange rate, but convenient)  change was given back in Icelandic.

Comment: Yes, they do. You are probably best off paying with a credit card if you are a transit passenger.